# Godot - How do I create a subarray of a list in Gdscript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I know it's possible to slice an array in python by array[2:4]. The way I get around this is to just loop through the indexes I want and append them to the new_list. This way requires more work is there just a simple way to do it like in python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.slice()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_array.html#class-array-method-slice) method added in Godot 3.2 for this purpose:

> Array **slice** ( int begin, int end, int step=1, bool deep=False )
>
> Duplicates the subset described in the function and returns it in an array, deeply copying the array if `deep` is `true`. Lower and upper index are inclusive, with the `step` describing the change between indices while slicing.

Example:

```py
var array = [2, 4, 6, 8]
var subset = array.slice(1, 2)
print(subset)  # Should print [4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks It works perfectly, I still need to learn the 3.2 features